# C++11 code with inheritance doesn't compile with clang

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, clang

I have a small program with such simple code:

```
namespace override
{
    using final = void();
}

namespace final
{
    using override = void(int);

    struct final
    {
        virtual override override;
        virtual ::override::final override;
    };
}

int main()
{
    struct final final : ::final::final
    {
        ::final::override override override final;
        ::override::final override final override;
    };

    // doesn't compile
    struct override : final
    {

    };        
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't compile. I tried to compile it with following pieces of code:

```
// 1
struct override final
{

};

// 2    
override : final
{

};
```

And both of these variants compile fine. Is it an error in my compiler (clang 3.4)? I can't also understand why my original code doesn't compile.

See [live example](http://rextester.com/RWW6858).

**Update:** It was an April Fool's day joke, of course. Thanks to all who participated in the discussion. I also thank [@ecatmur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567292/ecatmur) for his exact but too serious answer.

I wanted to get the code that would have looked strange and at the same time would have compiled with one compiler at least (because it would have given respectability to my question). So my goal was not to create a standard-compliant code. But as [**@Johannes Schaub - litb**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb) noted in comments this code has at least one problem which make it ill-formed. The line `virtual override override;` is a violation the following rule (see paragraph [basic.scope.class] 3.3.7/1 of the standard):

> A name `N` used in a class `S` shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of `S`. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

As I can see it can be rewritten as `virtual ::final::override override;` to become a standard-compliant.

Comment: When posting questions about compiler/linker errors, please always include the actual errors *in* the question, in full and unedited. Most likely it's because you are using keywords as names.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg An error is `error: base 'final' is marked 'final'`. What keywords do you mean?

Comment: @Jefffrey: _override_ and _final_ are no keywords. They are _identifiers with special meaning when appearing in a certain context_.

Comment: @Jefffrey No, they are not full-blown keywords like `struct` and `int`, see `2.11 [lex.name]`.

Comment: As far as I can tell you are marking `final` as final which means you can not use it as a base class ... do you have reason to believe this should not be the case?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour But why do other variants compile?

Comment: @Constructor I was just going to answer but ecatmur got to it first

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour OK. And what can you say about `final final` class contents?

Comment: Wow, all these serious answers. Am I really the only one around here who sees this as an April fools' prank?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an April Fool's joke.

Comment: Btw your code is illformed, no diagnostic required. That is the only thing that can be said about the code (and also the code that your implementation chooses to accept).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Why is this code ill-formed? Could you explain it, please? And why does clang compile it fine (see live example)?

Comment: @screwnut You are the first who noticed this, I think. Happy April Fools' Day!

Comment: @Constructor You know, I was still on the fence when I wrote that, reading all the genuine answers. I mean... it's C++ and C++ developers we're talking about. You never know! :)

Comment: @Constructor because of "virtual override override;", which is a violation of "a name must refer to the same declaration in its context and when reevaluated in the complete scope of the class"-rule.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb My goal was not to create a standard-compliant code because it was only a joke (I wanted to get the code that would compile with one compiler at least, it would have given respectability to my question). But thank you for your extremely valuable remark! I think this defect of the code can be remedied simply by changing `virtual override override;` for `virtual ::final::override override;`. So the code looks even more beautiful! But it still does not compile with g++ (due to other errors).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why would you expect it to compile? `final` is final, so you can't inherit from it.

In your other code:

```
struct override final
{

};
```

This is defining a final class with no base classes, so that's fine.

```
override : final
{

};
```

This is declaring a *label* `override`, and at that label creating a prvalue temporary of type `final` initialized with the brace-initializer `{}`, which is immediately destroyed:

```
override:
    final{};
```

Comment: `final` is final? What do you mean here? Your explanation for other variants is very interesting. But label variant is so strange to me...

Comment: If a class is final, then it cannot be inherited from.  This is a new feature in C++11.

Comment: Oh, in this meaning. I see. And what can you say about `final final` class contents?

Comment: It has two virtual functions both called `override`, one of type `void()` and the other of type `void(int)`, both of which override the corresponding overload of `override` in the base class, and both of which are marked `final` so they can't be overridden in any further derived class.

Comment: Excellent! Happy April Fools' Day (or Night which is more likely)!